# Get and set value to child component programmatically in angular

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I am creating a board game based on ionic, angular and html5. I have created two components app-board and app-square. app-square is child component of app-board component. app-square component as the following properties

```
      @Input() count: number = 0;
      @Input() type: string ="";
      coins(){
        return new Array(this.count);
      }
      setValue(own: string): boolean{//some code here}
```

board.component.html as several

```
<app-square (click)="makeMove(this)" [count]="3"></app-square>
```

board.component.ts is as follows

```
makeMove(obj){
    console.log(obj);
  }
```

when the app-square is clicked, it fires the makeMove method in the board.component. My question is how do i set or get the child component's properties from the makeMove method of board component?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Your code will set the given `AppSquareComponent`'s `count` to `3` as expected.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Please rephrase and show all relevant code.

Comment: Where is the child component? All I see is one component, which is the <app-square> component. You mentioned the board component, which is a parent component. So what object are you trying to pass?

Comment: I have edited it. Hope it explains

Answer (score 0):

```
<app-square (click)="makeMove(this)" [count]="3"></app-square>
```

is not what you want because `this` refers to the enclosing component, namely `app-board`. Just to drive the point home, `<app-square (click)="makeMove(this)">` is just in fact, shorthand for `<app-square (click)="this.makeMove(this)">`.

To get the desired behavior, passing the `<app-square>` to the `app-board`'s make move, 
You can declare a reference to the component and pass it into the method

```
<app-square #square (click)="makeMove(square)" [count]="3"></app-square>

@Component({ //...boilerplate and ceremony})
export class BoardComponent {
  makeMove(square: SquareComponent) {
    console.log(square);
  }
}
```